# SuperCSV skips first line while reading CSV file

Tags: java, csv, supercsv

I'm Using SuperCSV api to read CSV files and and validates their entries.
For a reason, it seems that every read it skips the first row.
i do not have Headers on my csvs, and i do need the first row.

I have tried using : CsvMapReader and CsvListReader, but every execute its starts printing only from Line No 2.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

I have tried using : CsvMapReader and CsvListReader, but every execute its starts printing only from Line No 2.

Here is a snippet of a code which i use to read the files.

```
listReader = new CsvListReader(new FileReader(CSV_FILENAME), CsvPreference.STANDARD_PREFERENCE);
listReader.getHeader(true); 
final CellProcessor[] processors = getProcessors();
List<Object> customerList;
while( (customerList = listReader.read(processors)) != null ) {
                        System.out.println(String.format("lineNo=%s, rowNo=%s, customerList=%s", listReader.getLineNumber(),                listReader.getRowNumber(), customerList));
}
```

Comment: Changing this line ->  listReader.getHeader(true);   to FALSE , doesnt solve the problem...

Comment: Well, you call getHeader(), and getHeader reads the first line. So the next line, that you print, is line 2. If you don't have a header row, why call getHeader()? The javadoc is your friend: https://super-csv.github.io/super-csv/apidocs/org/supercsv/io/AbstractCsvReader.html#getHeader-boolean-

Comment: Hello and thanks for your comment. I haven’t found any way of reading csv without the header. Do you have any clue how to do it?

Comment: Sure: you use the code you posted, but you removed the line `listReader.getHeader(true); `.

Comment: Hi :)
Lovely it works fine! Thanks for assistance.